# Cordova app not showing at correct screen-resolution on Android

Tags: android, cordova, retina-display, screen-resolution

I'm trying to run a Cordova app with a fullscreen canvas on an Android device with a devicePixelRatio of 2.
To compensate for this pixelratio I added `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no width=device-width initial-scale=0.5 minimum-scale=0.5 maximum-scale=0.5" />` to the head in the index.html, but for some reason it's ignored by Android when run as app.

window.innerWidth should show 1200 (the width of my tablet (nexus 7)) however window.innerWidth remains 600 just as it is with scale set to 1. When I set the scale to 2 the window.innerWidth becomes 300 so I'm sure the tag itself works (just not the 0.5 setting).

I also ran some test to see how other devices/browsers respond:
The regular chrome browser on the same tablet gives the correct innerWidth (of 1200).
Running the app on a iPhone SE also gives the correct innerWidth (of 640).

So the problem seems specific to Android running as an app.

Does anybody have a clue on how to force Android to run the Webview in the correct resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im still not sure why the meta-tag doesn't work, but I found a workaroud that works quite okay:

1. Make the canvas (which in my case should be 100% of the inner window size) twice as big as the inner window dimensions.
2. set the style.transform of the canvas to `scale(.5)`
3. set style.transformOrigin to `top left` to realign

`public setCanvasSize(width:number, height:number, pixelRatio:number = 1):void {
    if (pixelRatio == 1) {
        this._canvas.width = width;
        this._canvas.height = height;
        this._canvas.style.transform = '';
    }
    else {
        this._canvas.width = width * pixelRatio;
        this._canvas.height = height * pixelRatio;
        this._canvas.style.transform = 'scale(' +  (1 / pixelRatio) + ')';
        this._canvas.style.transformOrigin = 'top left';
    }
}`